# How to convert a character column to datetime in R

Tags: r

I have a chr column in the following format and need to convert it into datetime in R, keeping the same format. How do I do it?

`ts='10-MAR-21 08.07.14 PM'`

Comment: You can use `library(lubridate);dmy_hms(ts)`

Comment: Datetime objects do not have a format.

Comment: @akrun this works. Thanks!

Comment: @akrun Is there a way to ignore the timezone associated with the dates? All the dates in my column are in EST but in character. On conversion , by default it becomes UTC

Comment: You can specify the `tz =`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by akrun. You can use `dmy_hms` function from `lubridate` package.
Here is an example.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = dmy_hms(x))
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(x="10-MAR-21 08.07.14 PM")
```